# How to optimize GROUP BY on calculated field (to use index)?

Tags: mysql

I have a large (nearly 10M records) data table which, for performance reasons, has a secondary aggregation companion table. The aggregation table is regularly populated with sofar unaggregated data:

```
REPLACE INTO aggregate (channel_id, type, timestamp, value, count)
SELECT channel_id, 'day' AS type, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp, SUM(value) AS value, COUNT(timestamp) AS count FROM data 
WHERE timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d")) * 1000 
AND timestamp >= IFNULL((SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(timestamp)/1000, "%Y-%m-%d"), 
    INTERVAL 1 day)) * 1000 FROM aggregate WHERE type = 'day'), 0) 
GROUP BY channel_id, YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000)), DAYOFYEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000));
```

I've found that the `SELECT` part of the statement is pretty slow (2+ seconds on fast PC) even when no data is being returned. As the aggregation needs to be running on embedded devices this is a concern. Here is the plan:

```
id  select_type table       type        key     key_len rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     data        ALL                         9184560 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   SUBQUERY    aggregate   index       ts_uniq 22      1940    Using where; Using index
```

The sub-query itself is instant. Apparently `data` doesn't use the `channel_id/timestamp` index due to the calculation in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `channel_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `value` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ts_uniq` (`channel_id`,`timestamp`),
  KEY `IDX_ADF3F36372F5A1AA` (`channel_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10432870 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Can the query be further optimized?

**Update**: adding requested information

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM data;

Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Null    Index_type
data    0           PRIMARY     1               id          A           9184560             BTREE       
data    0           ts_uniq     1               channel_id  A           164         YES     BTREE       
data    0           ts_uniq     2               timestamp   A           9184560             BTREE       
data    1           IDX_ADF3..  1               channel_id  A           164         YES     BTREE       

CREATE TABLE `aggregate` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `channel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `value` double NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ts_uniq` (`channel_id`,`type`,`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1941 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I've also noticed that the query becomes instant when changing the GROUP BY to channel_id, timestamp. Unfortunately adding the data calculations as columns is not desirable as the grouping is dynamically calculated.

I'm failing to understand why the `GROUP BY` index should be such a problem when there isn't even any data to be grouped. I've tried running

```
SELECT channel_id, 'day' AS type, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp, SUM(value) AS value, COUNT(timestamp) AS count FROM data 
WHERE timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d")) * 1000 
AND timestamp >= IFNULL((SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(timestamp)/1000, "%Y-%m-%d"), INTERVAL 1 day)) * 1000 
    FROM aggregate WHERE type = 'day'), 0)
```

which is just as slow so the `GROUP` doesn't seem to be the problem?

**Update 2**

Digging further down that road shows that

```
SELECT channel_id, 'day' AS type, timestamp, value, 1 FROM data 
WHERE timestamp >= (SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(timestamp)/1000, "%Y-%m-%d"), 
    INTERVAL 1 day)) * 1000 FROM aggregate WHERE type = 'day');
```

is still slow (1.4sec)- so not a `GROUP BY` problem at all.

**Update 3**

And this is still slow:

```
SELECT channel_id, 'day' AS type, timestamp, value, 1 FROM data WHERE timestamp >= 1380837600000;
```

So- the problem is that the inner comparison is for timestamp which cannot make use of the channel_id, timestamp index although that is part of the `GROUP BY` clause. 
Which leads to the question on how to force that index?

Comment: would you mind to paste the `aggragate` table creating too?

Comment: Also, you can check if all indexes are being used properly with the command SHOW INDEXES FROM data; ... I have suspicion about (`channel_id`,`timestamp`) unique key ...

Comment: Can you try to replace `GROUP BY channel_id, YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000)), DAYOFYEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000)) ;` with `GROUP BY channel_id, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000)) ;`

Comment: An index on `(channel_id, timestamp, value)` would help.

Comment: You understand below, right? Your SQLs in update 2 and 3 are slow as expected because the index is not used 'as expected'. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html "If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to find rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3). "

Comment: That's what I wrote in update 3 an doesn't help solving the problem. Forcing the index e.g. by adding channel_id>0 AND... ist still extremely slow.

Answer (score 1):

Add a year and dayofyear column to data table, and have an index on (channel_id, year, dayofyear). Populate the two new columns when you insert a row.

Comment: Unfortunately not an option- and apparently not the problem either.